# Below is a screenshot of the Entry Point error I get when I try to load an mp3 file into my script

Tags: python, tensorflow, program-entry-point

[image]

```
def load_mp3_16k_mono(filename):
    """ Load a WAV file, convert it to a float tensor, resample to 16 kHz single-channel audio. """
    res = tfio.audio.AudioIOTensor(filename)
    # Convert to tensor and combine channels 
    tensor = res.to_tensor()
    tensor = tf.math.reduce_sum(tensor, axis=1) / 2 
    # Extract sample rate and cast
    sample_rate = res.rate
    sample_rate = tf.cast(sample_rate, dtype=tf.int64)
    # Resample to 16 kHz
    wav = tfio.audio.resample(tensor, rate_in=sample_rate, rate_out=16000)
    return wav
mp3 = os.path.join('folder', 'dataset', 'spoken_numbers.mp3')
wav = load_mp3_16k_mono(mp3)
```

This is my code. and I am getting entry point error. Can anyone help me, please?

I specifically mentioned the filepath, I don't know if that's the problem.

Comment: How you are running this code? Are you seeing any python error logs?

Comment: Here it is
NotImplementedError: unable to open file: libtensorflow_io.so, from paths: ['C:\\Users\\sifat\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python311\\site-packages\\tensorflow_io\\python\\ops\\libtensorflow_io.so']
caused by: ['C:\\Users\\sifat\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python311\\site-packages\\tensorflow_io\\python\\ops\\libtensorflow_io.so not found']

Comment: @Sifat-E-Jahan Welcome to Stack Overflow! Rather than adding details in comments, please [edit] your question to add information. Comments here may get hidden by "show more comments" or could be deleted without notice. Editing your question ensures that the additional information doesn't get lost and that everybody who wants to answer the question sees it.